# What is really meant by a nearest neighbor interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, interactions

Suppose there are three harmonic oscillators, which are spacially separated forming a chain where there are interactions only between nearest neighbors.
$$\require{enclose}
{\scriptstyle \enclose{circle}{\kern .6em \huge\omega_1^{} \kern .6em}} \longleftrightarrow {\scriptstyle \enclose{circle}{\kern .6em \huge\omega_2^{} \kern .6em}} \longleftrightarrow {\scriptstyle \enclose{circle}{\kern .6em \huge\omega_3^{} \kern .6em}}$$
The Hamiltonian for this system would typically be written along the lines of
$$
H = \left(\sum_i \omega_i \hat a_i^\dagger \hat a_i \right)+ (\gamma_{12} \hat a_1 \hat a_2^\dagger + \gamma_{23}\hat a_2 \hat a_3^\dagger + h.c.)
$$
where the term $a_1 a_3^\dagger$ is not included, afterall there is no direct interaction between $1$ and $3$.

But is this really the correct way to write a nearest neighbor interaction?

Consider now three (classical) capacitively coupled LC oscillators, which are coupled in the same manner. The description of this system would begin with a Lagrangian which only has nearest neighbor terms
$$
\mathcal L = \vec \phi \cdot C\cdot \vec \phi + l$$
$$
C =\begin{pmatrix} C1 & C12 & 0\\
C12 & C2 & C23\\
0 & C23 & C3\end{pmatrix} 
$$where $l$ are the terms from the inverse inductance matrix (which will not be relevant to the question).

When we quantize this system, we start by writting out the resulting classical Hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal H =  \vec \phi \cdot C^{-1}\cdot \vec \phi + l_{\mathcal H}$$
which depends on the inverse of the capacitance matrix. Therefore, when we quantize this system we get terms of the type $a_1 a_3^\dagger$ since $[C^{-1}]_{13}\neq 0$.

So what is really meant by a nearest neighbor interaction? That the Hamiltonian has only nearest neighbor terms or the Lagrangian? Note that these are the same only in the case that all the interactions are weak.

Comment: The short answer is that the Hamiltonian that matters. I don't have the will to write a proper answer for now, but specifically for cQED people consider the limit of small capacitances in order to get these NN Hamiltonians.